# SCIP with IpOpt and AMPL

Tags: ampl, scip, ipopt

I want to use SCIP with Ipopt and the AMPL interface to process `.nl-files.` The scip shell (without AMPL) includes Ipopt but is not able to read `.nl-files`. So I compiled the AMPL interface. But here, Ipopt does not seem to be included. The command `"scip-3.2.0/interfaces/ampl/bin/scipampl -i"` gives the following output.

> *SCIP version 3.2.0 [precision: 8 byte] [memory: block] [mode:
>   optimized] [LP solver: SoPlex 2.2.0] [GitHash: fb0007a]*
>
> Copyright (c) 2002-2015 Konrad-Zuse-Zentrum fuer Informationstechnik
>   Berlin (ZIB)
>
> External codes:
>
> Readline 6.2 GNU library for command line editing (gnu.org/s/readline)
>
> SoPlex 2.2.0 Linear Programming Solver developed at Zuse Institute
>   Berlin (soplex.zib.de) [GitHash: c9658ca]
>
> cppad-20140000.3 Algorithmic Differentiation of C++ algorithms
>   developed by B. Bell (www.coin-or.org/CppAD)
>
> ZLIB 1.2.7 General purpose compression library by J. Gailly and M.
>   Adler (zlib.net)
>
> GMP 6.0.0 GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library developed by T.
>   Granlund (gmplib.org)
>
> ZIMPL 3.3.3 Zuse Institute Mathematical Programming Language developed
>   by T. Koch (zimpl.zib.de)
>
> ASL AMPL Solver Library developed by D. Gay (www.netlib.com/ampl)
>
> number of parameters = 1882 non-default parameter settings:
>
> file <-i.nl> not found
>
> no problem exists
>
> [src/reader_nl.c:1694] ERROR: No AMPL problem read, cannot write AMPL
>   solution then.*

Under external codes Ipopt is not listed. I tried several variants of reinstalling, but none worked. Would you know a work around? Note, that I was not able to copy scipampl to my path since I don't have to right to use sudo. The OS is CentOS.

Greetings from Frankfurt,

Johannes

Answer (score 2):

When you build the SCIP/AMPL executable, you need to specify IPOPT=true again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried again without success. To be precise I used the following commands.
_cd /scipdir/interfaces/ampl/solvers_
_sh configurehere -"IPOPT=true"_
_make -"IPOPT=true"_
_cd .._
_make -"IPOPT=true"_

The output from the scipampl binary remains unchanged.

Comment: It should be just
     make IPOPT=true
without the dash in front. And do that only in scipdir/interfaces/ampl/.